# Why styles section in a single view can chage _Layout css?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

For example, in my _Layout.cshtml I declared:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/_Layout.css" />
@RenderSection("Styles", false)
```

And in my Index.cshtml view:

```
@section Styles 
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/Home/Index.css"/>
}
```

In `Index.css`, from my Index.cshtml view, if I made some change in some class or other selector of _Layout.cshtml (_Layout view), but in Index.css file (not referred as link in _Layout.cshtml view), the changes are applied, even the views are different. There are some reason for that?

And other question: It is normal bugs when running project with IIS express from Visual Studio? When I load the page the css isn't applied, and I need to make some change in css and then the css is applied.

**Edit:** The second question, about CSS not applied is because the browser (in my case, Brave) has "activated cache". This means that the browser stores information (like css info) about the page and then the new style is not applied. Run the project in anonymous mode or CTRL + F5 are the best solutions.